# Static Singleton Instance of Spring's ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I'm trying to port an application written with CURAM to a Struts2 project.  We are using Spring to take advantage of its database transaction capabilities.  Do to the way application code is written in a CURAM application, I cannot use the Dependency Injection feature of Spring.  I need to be able to access the Spring ApplicationContext from anywhere in my business logic.  And creating a new instance of ApplicationContext whenever I need it grinds things down to a screeching halt.

I found this resource on the internet that shows you how to create a static singleton instance of Spring's ApplicationContext.

[Access the Spring-ApplicationContext from everywhere in your Application](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/?p=154)

This would solve my issue, but I have concerns.  Wouldn't a static singleton instance mean that every user invoking a Struts2 action would be getting business objects from the same ApplicationContext instance?

By default, Spring beans are singletons within an ApplicationContext instance.  Because of this, I'm thinking that a static singleton instance of ApplicationContext would cause the same instance of all business objects to be used by all users / transactions, which would ruin transactions and probably cause locks all over the place.  Am I correct in assuming this?

What if I declared all of my Spring Beans as prototype?  Would that allow me to take advantage of Springs Database Transaction / Concurrency Handling capabilities while using a static-singleton instance of ApplicationContext?

Thanks.

Comment: transactions are managed through thread locals.  Spring already has that figured out.  However, I would suggest you run some multi-thread consistency checks, using e.g. jmeter, to ensure everything is ok, given some of the low level stuff you're digging into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Wouldn't a static singleton instance mean that every user invoking a Struts2 action would be getting business objects from the same ApplicationContext instance?

yes

> I'm thinking that a static singleton instance of ApplicationContext would cause the same instance of all business objects to be used by all users / transactions

yes

> which would ruin transactions and probably cause locks all over the place.

no. Why would that ruin transactions? Why would there be locks? A business service is typcically completely stateless, and is thus fine as a singleton. A typical Spring application only has a single application context, containing singleton beans. That's how it's designed to work. The transaction context isn't stored in the business objects. It's stored in a ThreadLocal.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Does this mean it is ok to use a static singleton instance of Spring's ApplicationContext for the application?

Comment: Yes, it's OK to do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you  create a class without   common variables, using siglton it will be the best choise. you can  @Autowired necessary сlass likes Dao or Services class

if your class will be prototype and you get the Bean from Applicationcontext every time it will be a new object